# Bash How to substitute multiple line variable and print both variables

Tags: bash, awk, sed, printf, snmp

I am doing snmp walks of devices to look at the status of interfaces. I am trying to replace the interface name with the device it came from so I can have the device name in the column beside the interface name.

**Expected Output**

DeviceName1 Device1InterfaceName1
DeviceName1 Device1InterfaceName2
DeviceName1 Device1InterfaceName3
DeviceName1 Device1InterfaceName4
DeviceName1 Device1InterfaceName5
DeviceName1 Device1InterfaceName6
DeviceName2 Device2InterfaceName1
DeviceName2 Device2InterfaceName2
DeviceName2 Device2InterfaceName3
DeviceName2 Device2InterfaceName4
DeviceName3 Device3InterfaceName1
DeviceName3 Device3InterfaceName2

I can run this script to get the interface name:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read device
do

var5=$(sm_snmp -c "communitystring" -d $device walk .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2 | grep -v "SNMP Walk MIB starting at" | awk -F "= " '{print $2}');

printf "%-20s\n" "$var5"

done < devicelist.txt
```

Output from script above gives me the InterfaceNames:

Device1InterfaceName1
Device1InterfaceName2
Device1InterfaceName3
Device1InterfaceName4
Device1InterfaceName5
Device2InterfaceName1
Device2InterfaceName2
Device2InterfaceName3
Device3InterfaceName1
Device3InterfaceName2

I would like to output the DeviceName and DeviceInterfaceName at the time. The problem I am having substituting is the output from the script above will return an DeviceInterfaceName on each line (which I want) but any substitution I have tried replaces the whole variable with just one line with the DeviceName. Also I would need to do this for each device in the devicelist.txt.

Comment: please add an output sample of your `/opt/InCharge/IP/smarts/bin/sm_snmp`

Comment: Added output sample.

Comment: It would be much easier for us to help you if you posted a few lines of your file `devicelist.txt` and also saved the output of `sm_snmp` to a file. You could do `sm_snmp -c "communitystring" -d $device walk .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2 > sm.txt` for example. Some real output and the corresponding desired output would be more useful than what you have currently shown. What is the value of `$device_walk`?

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "%-20s %-20s\n" "${device}" "${var5}"
```

is not what you expect ?